# Setting custom text on action button

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, ime

I read, that there is no other option after API v16, than to change the action button other than with standard imeOptions.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"           - (needed)
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"            - works
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/btn_apply" - does nothing
        android:imeActionId="@string/btn_apply"    - does nothing
        android:id="@+id/mEditText" />
```

of course 'in code' does nothing as well

```
newScoreEditText.setImeActionLabel("Apply", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

So is there absolutely no chance to **change the text from the action button** from "Done" to "Apply" using a std input type and not using a custom keyboard?
It just makes no sense to me and it's really annoying.

Comment: what about trying `newScoreEditText.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.xxx), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);`

Comment: As I mentioned above. It has no effect.